# Create a MVVM Light ViewModel via PCL? that will work for both Xamarin.Forms and WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xamarin, mvvm-light, xamarin.forms

I am trying to create an application using the MVVM Light framework that will work with WPF (4.5/4.5.1) (and perhaps future Windows 8.1) and with Xamarin.Forms 1.3.

I am trying to create two solutions - they will share a "Model" and "ViewModel" project (thinking PCL) but will implement their own UI in Xamarin.Forms and WPF.  I'm hoping to be able to databind to properties and commands in both solutions.  This would enable me to create one "engine/backend" for the app, but be able to implement a Windows 7/8, iOS and Android version (Windows Phone is not required).

I am struggling finding the correct NuGet package with the MVVM Light libraries that will compile both in Visual Studio for the WPF side and the other solution in Xamarin Studio on the Mac for the iOS and Android side.  One group will be doing the WPF work and another the iOS/Android work (and a third the services, so I'd like to be able to share the PCL-Models project with a WebAPI project).  I can get the shared Models project to work, but I'm having issues finding the right PCL/Profile/Package combination to work for this scenario.

Has anyone gotten something like this to work between Xamarin.Forms, WPF and MVVM Light 5

Comment: Having the same problem right now. Did you figured out how to handle it?

Comment: I'm writing a series of blog posts about creating a MVVMLight app - it's only android but it might help you.  http://www.jimbobbennett.io/building-an-android-app-part-1/

Comment: I'm struggling at the same project constellation. Do you have any code samples?

Answer (score 0):

Sure it works fine. Check your build targets on common Pcl library and mvvm light should be installed for whole solution.

Answer (score 0):

You create a blank solution, add a PCL and make sure you add the build targets correctly (I think it asks for them when you create the pcl project). Install MVVM light libraries only to this project. There, done. Now you can add Droid /iOS / forms / what ever and add MVVM light to them only (now install the non libraries only package, since you need the viewmodel locator it creates for you).